# Safe UPDATE JOIN in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-update, amazon-rds

TableA and TableB exist in an RDS MySQL DB.

TableB is a temporary table.

I want to achieve: TableA += TableB

I chose to use UPDATE JOIN as follows:

```
UPDATE TableA
JOIN TableB 
ON TableA.id = TableB.id
SET
    TableA.name = TableB.name,
    TableA.anotherid = TableB.someotherid;
```

But this is an unsafe update, so unless I add something like...

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
```

The query fails.

Even if I add...

```
WHERE id > 0;
```

Where "id" is an integer primary key, I still get an unsafe update error.

How can I achieve the desired outcome without disabling SQL_SAFE_UPDATES?

Thanks!

Comment: Well the query is a blanket update of the entire table, so technically it is unsafe.  I don't have an intellectual problem in turning off the safe updates flag.

Comment: Thanks @TimBiegeleisen, my boss is intuitively scared of turning the safe updates flag off, but if as you suggest this is the only way then I guess I'll have to convince him!

Comment: `I want to achieve: TableA += TableB` Does this means "add into A from B if the row is not present, and update otherwise"? If so then use REPLACE INTO or INSERT .. ODKU. *But this is an unsafe update .. How can I achieve the desired outcome without disabling SQL_SAFE_UPDATES?* Add fake condition by primary key column, for example, `WHERE TableA.id <= 4294967295` (for UNSIGNED INT datatype).

Comment: Thanks @Akina, I actually just want to fill two empty columns in TableA with two columns from TableB. Strangely, neither "WHERE TableA.id <= 4294967295" nor "WHERE TableA.id > 0" mitigated the unsafe update error...

Comment: *Strangely, neither "WHERE TableA.id <= 4294967295" nor "WHERE TableA.id > 0" mitigated the unsafe update error...* You do something wrongly... https://dbfiddle.uk/g0s9ZyNa